# Jenkins Shared Library resource not found

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-shared-libraries

I have just started looking into a shared libarary with jenkins in order to combine a load of scripts and pipelines across multiple repos that are pretty much identical.

I have the shared lib loaded and working but when tryign to execute the scripts i the resources folder i keep geting not found errors:

```
../releaseTagging-EO2DMYOPJ6JGB6JT5Q2RSFJWJWWPALA7F25H7CQNYBEV4ITTEB6Q@tmp/build.sh: not found
```

I am creating a copy of the file using the following:

```
createTempLocation(String path) {
  String tmpDir = pwd tmp: true
  return tmpDir + File.separator + new File(path).getName()
}
```

and

```
copyGlobalLibraryScriptcall(String srcPath, String destPath = null) {
  destPath = destPath ?: createTempLocation(srcPath)
  writeFile file: destPath, text: libraryResource(srcPath)
  echo "copyGlobalLibraryScript: copied ${srcPath} to ${destPath}"
  sh "chmod +x ${destPath}"
  echo "added executable permissions to ${destPath}"
  return destPath
}
```

I am then calling the last function thusly:

```
runBuild(Map config) {
    def script = copyGlobalLibraryScript('build.sh')
    sh script
}
```

(i realise i can collapse the above function in to one line)

This in turn then gets called via (trimed the whole file to relevent part):

```
pipeline {
        agent any
        stages {
            stage('Build') {
                steps {
                    timestamps {
                        checkout scm

                        bbNotify( key: buildKey, name: BuildName) {
                            runBuild()
                        }

                        stash includes: '**', name: 'RelToSTAN'
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

This all fails with the error at the top of the question, however when sshing on to the build server i can find that file int he location specified.

I dont understand why Jenkins cannot find it and execute it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue will be the following:
When using a java `File` object it‘ll always refer to some location on the Jenkins master. And of course it usually cannot run inside the sandbox.

On the other hand the `readFile` and `writeFile` methods always refer to some path on the build agent reserved by the `node` block where the call is encapsulated.

Long story short: Do not use the `File` class. Unfortunately you’ll need to create the temp path manually. But that shouldn’t be too hard.